# XML Parsing Google Maps API Trouble

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a markers to a google api map using data from a XML document, following the tutorial from this website:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

The xml file I am using is posted below.

```
<!--

- phpMyAdmin XML Dump
- version 4.7.0
- https://www.phpmyadmin.net
-
- Host: 127.0.0.1
- Generation Time: Aug 04, 2017 at 03:20 AM
- Server version: 10.1.25-MariaDB
- PHP Version: 7.1.7
-->
<pma_xml_export xmlns:pma="https://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/" version="1.0">
<!-- 
    - Structure schemas
     -->
<pma:structure_schemas>...</pma:structure_schemas>
<!-- 
    - Database: 'aogcc test'
     -->
<database name="aogcc test">
<!--  Table markers  -->
<table name="markers">
<column name="markers_id">1</column>
<column name="API_WellNo">50009100010000</column>
<column name="PermitNumber">1630190</column>
<column name="OpNo">136555</column>
<column name="WellName">ROMIG PARK INC</column>
<column name="WellNumber">1</column>
<column name="WellUnit">00000</column>
<column name="CurrentClass">EXP</column>
<column name="CurrentStatus">P&A</column>
<column name="CurrentDateStatus">1997-05-15 00:00:00</column>
<column name="PermitClass">EXP</column>
<column name="PermitStatus">1-OIL</column>
<column name="CompClass">EXP</column>
<column name="CompStatus">P&A</column>
<column name="DTD">11566</column>
<column name="TVD">11325</column>
<column name="Sales_Cd">NULL</column>
<column name="Actg_Grp">0</column>
<column name="Mult_Latrl">0</column>
<column name="CompNum">0</column>
<column name="Field_No">0</column>
<column name="Wh_GeoArea">820</column>
<column name="Wh_Lat">15.245</column>
<column name="Wh_Long">-152.54</column>
</table>
</database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

Using the following HTML Code:

```
html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 100;
        padding: 0;

      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.787172, -15.870226),
          zoom: 2
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('http://127.0.0.1:8080/markers.xml', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            window.alert(xml)


            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('table name="markers"');

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getElementsByTagName('column name="markers_id"');
              var name = markerElem.getElementsByTagName('column name="WellName"');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getElementsByTagName('column name="Wh_Lat"')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getElementsByTagName('column name="Wh_Long"')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However I am having difficulty parsing through the XML file to retrieve the Name, latitude and longitude to then feed to the google maps api.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your xml is invalid. There should be `&amp;` instead of &.
2. getElementsByTagName can only select elements by name. Adding attributes to the name won't work. So you have to iterate over all elements and filter what you need or use xpath to select elements with the attributes you need.

   ```
   var columns = markerElem.getElementsByTagName('column');

   var lat, lng;

   Array.prototype.forEach.call(columns, function(column) {
       if (column.getAttribute("name") == "Wh_Lat") {
           lat = column.firstChild.nodeValue;
       } else if (column.getAttribute("name") == "Wh_Long") {
           lng = column.firstChild.nodeValue;
       }
   });

   var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
   ```